# How to specify legend name in org plot

Tags: emacs, gnuplot, org-mode

I am using emacs org mode with plot. By default, the diagram generated by org-plot/gnuplot command uses column index number as legend name. I want to use the column name, how to do this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `org-babel-gnuplot`, which can be found [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-gnuplot.html)? I don't have much experience directly writing `gnuplot` code, but I think might be what you're looking for. You can pass your table by reference to a `gnuplot` code block, where you should be able to set the names of the legend entries.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of org-plot uses the column name, not the column index.
For example, this

```
#+PLOT: title:"Citas" ind:1 deps:(3) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]"
| Sede      | Max cites | H-index |
|-----------+-----------+---------|
| Chile     |    257.72 |   21.39 |
| Leeds     |    165.77 |   19.68 |
| São Paolo |     71.00 |   11.50 |
| Stockholm |    134.19 |   14.33 |
| Morelia   |    257.56 |   17.67 |
```

produces a legend named "H-index".

You can also use labels to name them whatever you want:

```
#+PLOT: title:"Citas" labels:("" "" "FOO") ind:1 deps:(3) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]"
```

names the legend entry "FOO".

Tested with Org-mode version 8.3.4 (release_8.3.4-801-gd1fb75 @ /home/nick/elisp/org-mode/lisp/)